# Splitting pairs from Column Data in SQL Server

Tags: sql, sql-server, split

I have a solution in Java for a simply defined problem, but I want to improve the time needed to execute the data handling. The problem is to take a series of words held in a column on a relational database and split the words into pairs which are then insert into a dictionary of pairs. The pairs themselves relate to a product identified by partid.

Hence the Part table has

```
PartID (int), PartDesc (nvarchar)
```

and the dictionary has

```
DictID (int), WordPair (nvarchar).
```

The logic is therefore:

```
insert into DictPair (wordpair, partid)
select wordpairs, partid from Part
```

A wordpair is defined as two adjacent words and hence words will be repeated, eg

```
red car with 4 wheel drive
```

will pair to

```
{red, car},{car, with}, {with,4}, {4, wheel}, {wheel, drive}
```

Hence the final dictionary for say partid 45 will have (partid, dictionarypair):

```
45, red car
45, car with
45, with 4
45, 4 wheel
45, wheel drive
```

This is used in product classification and hence word order matters (but pair order does not matter).

Has anyone any ideas on how to solve this? I was thinking in terms of stored procedures, and using some kind of parsing. I want the entire solution to be implemented in SQL for efficiency reasons.

Answer (score 3):

Basically, find a `split()` function on the web that returns the position of a word in a string.

Then do:

```
select s.word, lead(s.word) over (partition by p.partId order by s.pos) as nextword
from parts p outer apply
     dbo.split(p.partDesc, ' ') as s(word, pos);
```

This will put `NULL` for the last pair, which you don't seem to want.  So:

```
insert into DictPair (wordpair, partid)
    select word + ' ' nextword, partid, 
    from (select p.*, s.word, lead(s.word) over (partition by p.partId order by s.pos) as nextword
          from parts p outer apply
               dbo.split(p.partDesc, ' ') as s(word, pos)
         )
    where nextword is not null;
```

[Here](http://sqlperformance.com/2012/07/t-sql-queries/split-strings) are some split functions, provided by Googling "SQL Server split".  And [another](http://www.sqlservercentral.com/blogs/querying-microsoft-sql-server/2013/09/19/how-to-split-a-string-by-delimited-char-in-sql-server/).  And from [StackOverflow](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2647/how-do-i-split-a-string-so-i-can-access-item-x).  And there are many more